# Heroku Deployment succeed but not working

Tags: node.js, heroku

My app works fine locally but when I build and move to live using heroku it just fails and following error shown in logs for the url https://polar-hamlet-97953.herokuapp.com/

2018-05-26T05:33:54.026228+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:548:17
2018-05-26T05:33:54.026237+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-05-26T05:33:54.030198+00:00 app[web.1]: Loading adapter (`sails-mongo`) from this app's `node_modules/` directory...
2018-05-26T05:33:54.434024+00:00 app[web.1]: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!

Locally, it is in development mode and how to change it to production mode during deployment

Comment: I am seeing the same error when Mode is set to production as below NODE_ENV=production node app.js

Comment: looks like your database module is failing, i would check my dtabase connection .. and then troubleshoot onwards

Comment: I have created ticket at their site but they did not resolve it https://help.heroku.com/tickets/588238